# How do i Zoom-In the Jquery Portlet in click of "zoom-in" icon?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have searched the forums and did not find any post relevant to my problem so I am posting my query.
I have Four Jquery Portlets on my page.What I want to do is zoom-in a portlet on click of "Zoom-in" icon that will overshadow all other contents of page and zoom-out on click of "close" button.
I have tried out jQuery "animate()" function. That does not work for me.
Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could this help at all?

http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

I think it's just too amazing, if not you should have it lol :) Hope it helps.

Also, on mozila its this on css

`body {-moz-transform:scale(2)}`

I am assuming on css3 you can also use -webkit-, but if you google, zoom, or scale,

http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/ here is another source,

http://www.solucior.com/15-Zoom_with_CSS3.html

Comment: I think it may be Internet explorer only, but worth a shot :) they all are beautiful :) mark answer as the right answer if it solved the problem by clicking on the `check list tick` on the right so it's green